# Does slick support NULLS NOT DISTINCT in table definitions

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Is it possible to define such index using slick table definitions:

```
ALTER TABLE user_group
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (age_group_id, location_id);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/detail/392/

Comment: FYI, this is only available in Postgres 15+.